# Data Transformation / Preparation

Tags: python, data-transform

I'm beginner in Python. In order to perform data mining, I would like to transform a raw dataset:

```
PurchaseLine01  PurchaseLine02  PurchaseLine03  PurchaseLine04
milk              egg               sausage  
butter            water      
egg               sugar              cake           water
```

Into this dataset:

```
    milk    egg    sausage  butter  sugar   cake    water
1   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
3   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

Is there a simple way in Python to achieve this task?

Comment: Hi, what is concretely the problem with this question ?

Comment: I would really be interested to see a smart solution to this, as well!

Comment: Hi @Krukiou. Can you handle `pd.DataFrame`s?

Comment: Hi @ thanasissdr. Yes I can handle pd.DataFrame. However I think, i need loop. Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. In deed, i just posted an extract of my DataFrame. The whole DataFrame has 9835 rows and 32 columns.

Comment: Congratulations. I'm impressed...! Thanks you.

Comment: No worries, mate! You are welcome!

Comment: Notice that there is a caveat in the given solution. Within the function `get_series` `df` is called which is the initial DataFrame. Edit the function accordingly to make the code more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your data is in a DataFrame called `df`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = np.unique(df.stack().values).tolist() 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=range(len(df))) 

def get_series(string): 
    return (df == string).T.any() 

for col in cols: 
    new_df[col] = get_series(col) 
new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `get_dummies()` function from pandas for the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I already used this function : The problem is that it create 2 attributes : for example "PurchaseLine02_water" and "PurchaseLine04_water" and I want just only one attribute ("water") with "TRUE" (or "1"), in the right row.